# LED Driver Components

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, driver

What electronic components is a constant current LED driver made of? And what are the different components in constant voltage LED driver.

Comment: Open some driver datasheet and look at the schematic/block diagram.

Comment: @NiharPatel: You haven't accepted an answer to any of your previous questions. Please consider addressing this or seeking some clarification in the comments on those answers. This question shows no sign of study or research so it is likely to be closed.

Comment: Very vague question. A constant current LED driver can be made in so many ways. Can you read a datasheet, post a schematic, and ask a specific question?

Answer (score 1):

> What electronic components is a constant current LED driver made of?

The answer is resistors, capacitors and transistors. There are hundreds of ways to build a constant current circuit.

Current mirrors:

[image]

Or

An op amp:

[image]

Many constant current circuits involve a negative feedback pathway to regulate the current.

Answer (score 1):

There are as many ways as allowed by human imagination. But let's enumerate a few:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxisCu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From left to right:

- The current in the LED is \$I_{LED}\approx \frac{700\:\textrm{mV}}{R_1}\$. \$R_2\$ must drop \$V_{SUPPLY}-V_{LED}-700\:\textrm{mV}\$ and must supply a current \$I_{R_2}\ge I_{LED}+I_{C_1{MIN}}\$. This circuit works when \$V_{SUPPLY}\$ isn't well known or varies. \$V_{SUPPLY}\gt V_{LED}+700\:\textrm{mV}\$ and, if you want this to work over a variable suppply voltage then the LED current may vary too much if you don't set \$I_{C_1{MIN}}\ge I_{LED}\$.
- The current in the LED is \$I_{LED}\approx \frac{V_{SET}-700\:\textrm{mV}}{R_3}\$. This circuit also works when \$V_{SUPPLY}\$ isn't well known or varies. However, it requires another low impedance voltage source, \$V_{SET}\$, and \$V_{SUPPLY}\ge V_{SET}+V_{LED}+700\:\textrm{mV}\$; which isn't always convenient.
- Current mirror where the current in the LED (assuming \$R_5=R_6=0\:\Omega\$) is \$I_{LED}\approx \frac{V_{SUPPLY}-700\:\textrm{mV}}{R_4}\$. This has an advantage of being able to work with rather low overhead and even with \$Q_3\$ is in a fair bit of saturation. Also, with matched BJTs (later) this circuit has good stability over temperature variations. Discrete current mirrors can be a problem, though, as BJTs vary a lot. But there are suitable dual BJT packages like the BCV61/62 and BCM61/62. \$R_5\$ and \$R_6\$ (if the same value) can help compensate for BJT variation. Arrange them to drop several hundreds of millivolts, if so. Also, with the use of one or the other or both of \$R_5\$ and \$R_6\$ (if both, then different values) allows you to either diminish (divide down) or increase (multiply up) the LED current vs the current in \$R_4\$. Versatile arrangement. But perhaps over-kill.

---

Variations can make more sense. Let's take the left two schematics from above and combine them to get rid of \$V_{SET}\$ (left side below) and also provide a slight improvement to handle discrete BJTs for the right-most schematic above (right side below):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3g2Bh.png)</sup>

Note that in the left side schematic I have used the left-most above schematic to drive a current source through \$R_8\$, which sets up a known value for \$V_{SET}\$. This is now tied to the original base of \$Q_2\$ in the middle schematic above so that you don't need a separate supply.

This also has a slight other advantage: if the temperature of the BJTs rise, their \$V_{BE}\$ declines by about \$-2\:\frac{\textrm{mV}}{^\circ\textrm{C}}\$. This would reduce \$Q_1\$'s \$I_{SET}\$. But oppositely, this effect would increase \$Q_2\$'s \$I_{SET}\$. Putting them together like this means that the reduction of \$Q_1\$'s \$I_{SET}\$ leads to a lower voltage at the base of \$Q_2\$, which would otherwise reduce \$Q_2\$'s \$I_{SET}\$. But since the temperature is also affecting \$Q_2\$, which would normally increase \$Q_2\$'s \$I_{SET}\$, the two effects have the net effect of reducing the thermal sensitivity.

The right side schematic adds a \$\beta\$-compensation resistor, \$R_7\$. Together with setting \$R_5=R_6\$ and where \$V_{R_5}=V_{R_6}\ge 200\:\textrm{mV}\$ (or as much as you are willing to afford them), it can work pretty well with discrete BJTs.

---

To close, there is another way that is really, really simple. Just use a ***huge*** voltage source in this following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnl4U6.png)</sup>

It's simple, so long as the Dc power supply is very much larger than the required LED voltage. Like 50 or 100 or even 1000 times larger. The current in the LED will be \$I_{LED}\approx \frac{V_{SUPPLY}-V_{LED}}{R_9}\$. But given the criteria here, it's really just \$I_{LED}\approx \frac{V_{SUPPLY}}{R_9}\$. And since you control both of those, the current in the LED is effectively constant whether you use a white LED or a red LED. Here, you are buying simplicity with having to create a high potential difference.

(Which points out the corollary fact that when you use a simple current limiting resistor for an LED, the more "overhead" you have the better the current limiting effect will be.)

---

The above only scratches the surface. The only reason I stopped is that there's limited time to list them. A compendium would occupy at least a chapter, if not an entire book. I certainly haven't addressed how it is done in many constant current IC regulators for LED drivers. I haven't addressed how it would be handled using MOSFETs. I haven't addressed the Wilson varieties of the current mirror. And I haven't addressed Michael Wyatt's really interesting circuit, either. And there are so many variations on these themes.

Your question requires a book, I think. So this last 10 minutes is all I'm spending here.